# How to extract readable format report from jacoco.exec?

Tags: jacoco

I have a jacoco-agent generated file of my Maven project (Java), named `jacoco.exec`. 
How can I convert this file into human readable format? (HTML/XML).

Answer (score 9):

I believe that this is described in [official JaCoCo documentation](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/). In particular there is [jacoco-maven-plugin goal "report"](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html) and [example of its usage](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom.xml).

Starting from JaCoCo version 0.8.0 there is also [Command Line interface](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html). Here is an example of how to use it to produce HTML report from `jacoco.exec`, note that this also requires class files:

```
java -jar jacoco-0.8.1/lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --classfiles directory_with_classes --html directory_for_report
```

Comment: i am new in maven project . can you please refer the steps. do i need to write another  programe to get report or is there any plugin available?

Comment: @avy yes - there is a plugin and examples of its usage are given in documentation: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html

Comment: @kryger why? `report` goal of `jacoco-maven-plugin` as well as `report` task of `JaCoCo Ant Tasks` both turn `exec` file into `html` report.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you could use `dataFile` to change execution data source, turning the plugin into a "converter". This still doesn't solve some use cases (like mine: I generated jacoco.exec by adding the Jacoco agent to my production JVM so I can't use the Maven plugin, I was looking for a generic alternative to "import in IDE and export as HTML from there"), OP didn't mention explicitly how they obtained their .exec file.

Answer (score 6):

In the Gradle world (for anyone who happened to stumble upon this question), use the `JacocoReport` task, documented [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_configuration).

The configured task would look something like this:

```
jacocoTestReport {
  reports {
    html.enabled = true
    html.destination "${buildDirectory}/coverage/report/html"

    xml.enabled = true
    xml.destination "${buildDirectory}/coverage/report/xml"
  }
  executionData = files("path/to/jacoco.exec")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Godin's answer is perfect. But if you are using maven, then you can simply run the following command

```
mvn clean verify
```

As Jacoco's report goal is attached to the verify phase of maven life cycle.
`mvn verify` would simply invoke the `report` goal, and will generate all the reports in the following path

```
./target/site/jacoco
```